# Tesseract data language codes with country name

Tags: tesseract

Tesseract updated their iOS library and training data. The training data is with language codes. How can I know which language is this and to which country it belongs? I searched all Google for this. Some codes are understandable but not all. i.e.

1. asm.traindata
2. aze.traindata
3. bel.traindata
4. ben.traindata
5. bod.traindata
   ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those file names are ISO 639-2/T or ISO 639-2/B language codes. [IN THIS WIKI ARTICLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) you can find the whole table of languages and their codes, so finding out to which language those files belong should be easy.